# Multiple UIView with 0.5 height constraint not rendered the same way

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a vertical UIStackView and i populate it with some UIView's that has a fixed 0.5 height constraint set for them. This is how i create the lines:

```
for article in articles {
    let border = UIView()
    border.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "color-hr")
    border.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    articlesContainer.addArrangedSubview(border)
    border.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0.5).isActive = true
}
```

However, once rendered on the phone, the lines are different in height. Any ideas what might cause this?

[image]

Comment: what is you stack view setup? did you try setting `distribution` to `.equalSpacing`?

Comment: my main stackview(articlesContainer) was .fill, i changed it to .equalSpacing now but i can see the same problem

Comment: What is the point of a 0.5-height view? You cannot draw a fraction of a pixel, so this same view can easily appear in different ways (with different pixel heights) depending where it occurs on the screen.

Comment: its 1px at 2x and 1.5px(1px + a subpixel) at 3x. I just want a very thin line basically :)

Comment: 0.5 is a number of _points_, not pixels. It has to be scaled to the screen resolution and translated into pixels for you in order to display it on the screen. Hence the inconsistency depending on the screen resolution and the location on the screen. To get a consistent thin line, you need to take account of the screen resolution yourself, and you need to eliminate fractions throughout the layout.

Comment: Did you check it on an actual device? I have experienced that the simulator may do the interpolation differently depending on how it is resized.